# When using Lasso and calling coefficients (.coef_) which is the coefficient of the constant?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, lasso, linear, intercept

By calling *.coef* on the Lasso model built, there are only numbers corresponding to the coefficients.

These coefficients are supposed to match, say, the columns of the pandas dataframe given as input. However, if the *fit_intercept* parameter has been set to *True*, then which of the coefficients is the constant or the y-intercept?

Regarding this is it the same to set optional parameter *fit_intercept* to *True* as adding a constant with *.add_constant(x)* in the Lasso model?.

Answer (score 1):

The y-intercept will be the last coefficient in your weight vector, in the case where fit_intercept=True.

Not sure about the .add_constant(x) function but if it concatenates a list of 1s to your dataframe, then yes, it is the same as the fit_intercept parameter. In this case, you will want to check if it's doing pd.concat([data,ones],'1') or pd.concat([ones,data],'1') to retrieve its correct weight from coef_.

Comment: Thank you so much Luis!